# How to line break (resize only vertically, add height) in span/div elements automatically with angular interpolation binding without changing variable

Tags: css, angular, data-binding, resize, overflow

We can auto increment the height of a span element using methods showing below in section "Solution with span":

**HTML**

```
<p>
  <strong>Solution with span:</strong> 
  <span class="textarea" role="textbox" contenteditable>
  </span>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

**Source:**
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/XWbqpzP [0](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/XWbqpzP)

##### But it doesn't work with angular! Because the value bound by angular is loaded later and the overflow will not be taken into account. The value just go straight out of span or be simply hidden if `overflow: hidden` is added to the style.

**example.component.html:**

```
<p>
  <span class= "textarea" #FieldNameLabel contenteditable role="textbox">
    {{example.value}}
  </span>
</p>
```

**css version with `overflow:hidden`**

I put `resize: vertical` because I only wish the height increase as the string length in variable becomes longer and longer.

```
.textarea {
  display: block;
  min-width: 17rem;
  max-width: 75%;
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 0.8rem;
}
```

[Generated effect with overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7hA1.png)

If I remove `overflow: hidden;`, the effect will be like this, the value just go out of span:

```
.textarea {
  display: block;
  min-width: 17rem;
  max-width: 75%;
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  resize: vertical;
  padding-top: 0.8rem;
}
```

[Generated effect without overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anfhm.png)

So can someone help me with a piece of code that can increase automatically the height of a div/span element based on the string length of variable using One-way from data source to view target binding (interpolation) in Angular?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

since there is nobody answer me the question, I am going to give one possible solution: Use a textarea with a directive to control its resize instead of using a contenteditable span!

Source code of the directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[textAreaAutoResize]'
})
export class TextareaAutoresizeDirective implements OnInit {
  
  @HostListener(':input')
  onInput() {
    this.resize();
  }

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  resize() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.height = 'auto';
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.height = this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }

  
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollHeight) {
      setTimeout(() => this.resize());
    }
  }
}
```

An example textarea which replaces the original one (contenteditable span)

```
<textarea class= "field-name-label" #FieldNameLabel textAreaAutoResize role="textbox">{{example.value}}</textarea>
```

If anyone has a solution using a normal element like ("span", "div", "p", etc) with "contenteditable" which are able to adjust size according to angular binding variables, you are welcome to post it below.